# Eagle footprint - create a pin row

Tags: pcb, components, eaglecad, footprint

I am trying to create my first footprint for Eagle.
Specifically, it is the HC-06 breakout board for the Arduino.

This component has a row of four pins right next to each other.

Is there a way to create a pin row in Eagle? I am sure there has to be a way, because placing individual pads one by one seems really inefficient - plus it is not easy to find the coordinates of each pad in this situation.

EDIT:
Something is not right and i am not able to understand what it is.
I measured the dimensions of the board, and the distance of the pad from the edges of the board.

[image]

The reason is i tried to find the coordinates of the first pad.
So for the X axis, i got the length (0.63 inches) of the board and divided by /2 to get the distance from the edge to the center. Then i subtracted 0.01 inches, to get the position of the center of the pad, in relation to the center. This is -0.305 inches for the X axis.

I put the minus sign because it is to the left, compared to the center. Then i did the same for the Y axis.

The distance between them is 0.1 inches, and i set the grid size to be 0.1 as well. Then theoretically, i could just copy the pads, and place them right next to each other on the grid, to get the realistic part.

I did exactly that but now all the parts are on the left side of the board - in relation to its center (the cross in the picture).

[image]

Obviously, something is wrong, but i cannot understand what i did wrong....

Comment: I don't use Eagle, so don't know if there is an easy way to place an array of pins - but for only four pins there should be little need for automation.  The pins are almost certainly on 0.1 inch centers.  If you set the placement grid to 0.1 inch, it will be trivial to place the pins correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I used your method but something is wrong. I updated the question.

Comment: You should read all the Eagle Info about footprint design. There is a pretty good explanation.

Comment: Start by placing the pins on the placement grid - they should snap into position.  Then you can draw the component outline relative to the pin positions.  The important part of a component footprint is the pad/pin position (and position of any mounting holes).  The component outline is just decoration, although it does give you some guidance to avoid placing parts so they interfere.

Comment: I suggest placing pin 1 at position 0,0.  If the pins are on the grid, routing to them will be much easier.

Comment: @Uwe Could you explain why this happens?

Comment: @PeterBennett I know, as you can see in the last image, i don't even have an outline drawn. Even if i follow your suggestion and place the first pad at (0,0) then still the rest of the pads will be wrong. The measurements and the placement doesnt line up.

Comment: If you have the snap grid set to 0.1 inch (don't use mm!), and set pin 1 at 0,0, the other pins should be at 0.1,0, 0.2,0 and 0.3,0 - the pins should just snap to the grid at those positions - no calculations required.  There appears to be an error in your drawin, showing a pin 0.01 inch from the edge of the part - that would leave part of the pad for the pin hanging off the edge of the part.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino's pin header are fairly common (2.54 mm pitch pin header). I think there is already the footprint you're looking for in EAGLE (example MA04-1 in the con-lstb library). You may need two of those and adjust the separation distance

If you really want to do your own, you can look the "pattern" tool, or you always have the good old group copy/paste (You may want to adjust your grid to 2.54mm for an easy positioning of your pads)

Comment: Thank you. Since i am a newbie, i decided to just place them right next to each other on a 0.1 inches grid (their centers is 0.1 inches apart). However there was something wrong. I updated the question. If you could take a look at it, i would be greateful! Thanks!